# Is it possible to test whether something is constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr, c++17

In C++11 and later, is it possible at compile-time for any given identifier to derive (without compile errors) a `constexpr bool` value, which is `true` if and only if that given identifier refers to a `constexpr` variable?

If not, why? If yes, how? Is it also possible to detect `constexpr` functions?